# "Want to see my mother smile" vs "Want to see my mother smiling"

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, tenses

I would be happy if my mother smiled. My mother never smiled. In this case, which sentence should I use?
1. I want to see my mother smile always.
2. I want to see my mother smiling always.

Another context is that, My mother is always happy. She has a smile on her face always. I am happy when I see my mother is smiling. In this case, which sentence should I use?
1. I want to see my mother smile always.
2. I want to see my mother smiling always.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to see my mother smile" is general and not tied to a specific moment, you just want to see her smile at some unspecified point in time. In context, it CAN imply that she never smiles, but it does not have to.

For example, if I get her a funny gift and someone asks me why I'd choose something so silly, I could respond "I want to see my mother smile" but it also works in your context too.

For your example, I'd probably expand it a bit and say "I'd like to see my mother smile one day" or "i'd really like to see her smile sometime" etc.

The second option sounds ok on the surface, but as a native AE speaker, I can't honestly think of why/how I'd ever say that. My feeling is that it's wrong but I can't say why exactly!

You could say "My mother is always smiling" to refer to a frequent repeating activity.

Comment: About the implication whether she never smiles, that is very dependent on which word is stressed. Compare "I want to see _my mother_ smile", "I want to see my mother _smile_", "I want to _see_ my mother smile", "I _want_ to see my mother smile." and "_I_ want to see my mother smile". All of these have different implications attached to them.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean here by saying different implications. could you tell me the different implications attached to them?